# Rerun window.onload function

Tags: javascript

I have a script that is beeing executed, when loading the page. I would like to rerun the script, when the user gives an input.

I recreated the problem here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Simon_R/xtdv4e6k/)
– How can I make it, so that the `"Run Again"` button actually makes the function run again?

HTML:

```
<button onclick="timerAll()">
Run Again
</button>
```

JS:

```
function timerAll() {
  window.onload = function () {
  alert("alert");
  }
}
timerAll();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, it's actually pretty easy:

HTML

```
<button onclick="timerAll()">
Run Again
</button>
```

JS

```
function timerAll() {
  alert("alert");
}
timerAll();

window.onload = timer()
```

Comment: I actually tried this before posting the question, but my mistake was, that I added the `onload` part before I wrote the function…  Can someone accept this, as the answer? – Simon